# How to enable paste keyboard shortcut in Mac X11 xterm?

Tags: macos, x11, xterm

On my mbp, I open xterm under X11 and I want to paste from the clipboard. However, command+v doesnt work and there isnt even an option from the edit menu. Is this not possible? If it is, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the Pasteboard settings in X11?  Also, a lot of keyboard shortcuts for X11 actually use ctrl instead of Command (like in GIMP and Inkscape).

[Previous Stack answer](https://superuser.com/questions/17474/sharing-the-mac-os-x-clipboard-with-the-internal-x-server)

Secondly, is there a reason that you're using Xterm instead of Terminal?

Answer (score 7):

Alt + left mouse click should do the job if the button mouse emulation has been enabled.
And for some more details check this out http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-18272.html.